# System Bootloader not found

Tags: grub2, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi

I have preinstalled Windows 10 in my HP Probook 450 G4. Then I installed Ubuntu with manual partition, where it shows that EFI system partition is needed. So, I created it. My partition for Ubuntu was like this:

```
/dev/sda7 swap 8191MB

/dev/sda8 efi 256MB

/dev/sda9 ext4 / 34503
```

But after the installation the system can not find the grub menu for dual boot. It shows "no system bootloader found" and continues to restart.

How can I get the grub menu now?